# Solve a logarithmic equation 5

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Find the set of solution of the following equation in R
$$2 x^3 \left(\log{x}\right)^2 =5 $$
I tried the sub $$x=10^y$$ to be
$$\left(10^{3y}\right)y^2=\frac{5}{2}$$
Then i took log to both sides again to be
$$3y +2\log{y}=\log{5}-\log{2}$$
But i did not go throw more

Comment: a numerical method will help you!

Comment: Thank you ,but the solution is required analytical , does it exist ?@Dr.SonnhardGraubner

Comment: For $log$ the base is $e$ or $2$?

Comment: are you sure that you made no typos?

Comment: The base is 10 @GhD

Comment: Yes, the question is mentioned in the exam of Math is a secondary school , and they unaware with the numerical methods @D

Comment: This equation seems to have no "nice" solution. There is a solution near $2.5$

Comment: Wolfram Alpha gives $x=2.50499\dots$, and doesn't give any analytic solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$x^3(log x)^2=x(xlogx)^2=\frac{5}{2}$

$x(log x^x)^2=\frac{5}{2}$

x can not be equal to one because $log 1=0$ so we may assume $x=\frac{5}{2}=2.5$ . Also $log 2.5^{2.5}≈0.99..≈1$, Therefore $x≈2.5$ can be a solution.